# New: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/main/OptionName: com.sun.tools.javac.main.OptionName

Tags: maven, java-8, gatk

I am trying to build GATK 3.4.  Downloaded the 3.4 [tagged source](https://github.com/broadgsa/gatk/releases/tag/3.4) from github

I have JAVA_HOME set to a Java 8 JDK and that the JDK java is first on my PATH

1: Code doesn't compile.  gatk-3.4/public/gatk-tools-public/src/main/java/org/broadinstitute/gatk/tools/walkers/annotator/interfaces/AnnotationInterfaceManager.java has this line:

```
for ( Class c : classes )
    annotations.add((T)pluginManager.createByType(c));
```

That fails to compile until I added the "(T)"

3: Then I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project external-example: Fatal error compiling:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/main/OptionName:
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.OptionName -> [Help 1]

This is usually an error caused by not compiling with java 8.  But my JAVA_HOME is set correctly.  So what is it I still have wrong?

Comment: I recommend to use a more recent version of that https://github.com/broadgsa/gatk/tags ?? version 3.4 is of 2015 which. is a bit out-of-date...

Comment: I can't.  3.4 has features that were removed in 3.5, that our pipeline uses

Comment: Than you have to migrate to newer version...